# Make nested child element full width of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am unable to make a nested child element the full width of the browser, I am wondering if I am missing something easy here.

I created a fiddle showing what I am trying to do here: http://jsfiddle.net/MrHunter/r2tr6yxu/

Basically I've tried making the position absolute and left, right: 0.

```
.child_full_width {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I've tried making it fullwidth using jQuery but the width between the content and left side of the screen is always different.

Wondering if anyone else has overcome this problem?

Comment: Absolute positioning takes the nearest ancestor element with position relative as reference point – so no, this is not possible with the constellation you have here.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `position:relative` from main parent.

```
.parent {
width: 90%;
background-color: #FF0;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/r2tr6yxu/3/)

Comment: You beat me too it Surresh!